# SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: web-services, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy my application pharma.ear onto JBOSS EAP 6.3 but getting an error:

```
17:23:42,622 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.server.http] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:181) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:83) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:318) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.createBinding(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:325) [classes:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:264) [classes:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:156) [classes:2.1.3]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:83) [jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:144) [jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:178) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.1.3]
```

I have saaj-impl.jar and saaj-api.jar in my pharma.war/WEB-INF/lib.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you deploy the ear file on another app server, e.g. JBoss 7.1.1.Final. This is just to verify that the issue is not with your ear file.

Also try not bundle the SAAJ jar with your war/ear file. Let JBoss pick it up from it own modules. In Maven you can do that by provided